# Is there a way to get help for some C functions inside of vim/Neovim?

Tags: c, neovim

This question may be a little off topic. But I was wondering if there was a way for me to look at the descriptions of `C` functions using `vim` or `neovim`. Is it possible to look at their documentations by doing something like `:help`? This would really be helpful since I wouldn't need to lookup to my browser everytime.

I am unclear about these things:

- Can `:help` be my friend here ?
- Can I use LSPs to do something like this ?
- I am using latest `Neovim` inside `Ubunutu 20.04` in `WSL`. Is this helpful somehow ?

Comment: See `:help K` for that.

Answer (score 3):

By pressing `K`, the keyword under the cursor is looked up using a configured keyword lookup program, the default being `man`. This works pretty much out of the box for the C standard library.

For C++, you might want to look at something like [cppman](https://github.com/aitjcize/cppman).

Answer (score 1):

Well yes, you can get the description of `C` functions by using a LSP (language server plugin)! Here is an image of me using [`clangd`](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#clangd) as my LSP:
[image: information example]

You'd "just" need to install the LSP and start it. I don't know how familiar you're with neovim, but just in case if you don't know how to install a plugin or to be more specifique: If you don't know how you can install a LSP server, then you can do the following:

1. There're plenty videos how to set up a LSP-Server for your language. Here's an [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6F3ONwrCxMg).
2. If you don't want to set up on your own, you can pick up one of the [preconfigured neovim setups](https://github.com/rockerBOO/awesome-neovim#preconfigured-configuration) (some of my friends are recommending [lunarvim](https://github.com/LunarVim/LunarVim))

But yeah, that's it. If you have any further questions feel free to ask them in the comments.

Happy vimming c(^-^)c

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer recommending `cppman` is the way to go. There is no need to install a bulky language server just for the purpose of having the `hover` functionality. However, make sure you're caching the man pages via  `cppman -c`. Otherwise, there will be a noticeable delay since `cppman` is fetching the page from cppreference.com on the fly.

If you like popups for displaying documentation, convert the uncompressed man pages (`groff -t -e -mandoc -Tascii <man-page> | col -bx`), and set `keywordprg` to your own wrapper to search for keywords according to your needs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's explain how "K" command works in more detail.

- You can run external commands by prefixing them with `:!` command. So running `man` tool is as easy as

```
:!man <C-R><C-W>
```

Here `<C-R><C-W>` is a special key combination used to put word under cursor from text buffer down to command line.

Same for showing Vim's built-in help page

```
:help <C-R><C-W>
```

- As it feels tedious to type that, Vim also defines <kbd>K</kbd> Normal mode command that does pretty much the same thing. Except the tool name is taken from value of an option named "keywordprg".

So doing `set keywordprg=man` (default for *nix systems) makes <kbd>K</kbd> to invoke `!man` tool; while `set keywordprg=:help` is for bultin help.

Also, the option `:h 'keywordprg'` is made global or local-to-buffer, so any Vim buffer is able to overwrite global setting. For example, this is already done by standard runtime for "vim" and "help" buffers, so they call ":help" instead of "man".

- The problem with `:!man` command is that it shows "black console". It'd be nice if we could capture man's output and open it inside Vim just like a builtin help page. Then we could also apply some pretty highlighting, assign key macros and all such. This is a pretty common trick and it is already done by a standard plugin shipped with Vim/Neovim.

A command that the plugin provides is called `:Man`, so you can open `:Man man` instead of `:!man man`, for example. The plugin is preactivated in Neovim; for Vim you still need to source one file manually. So to make use of this plugin you'll need something like this

```
set keywordprg=:Man
if !has("nvim")
    source $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/man.vim
endif
```